# Facebook SDK for iOS Open Graph Stories

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I was able to post `Facebook` status using `Open Graph Stories` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios

But then, i think another guys change setting for app on `developers.facebook.com` and it cannot work anymore.

I received an Error : `"App myAppId is not allowed to create actions of type myNameSpace:myAction for user userID"`

Can somebody help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message shows that your application is not allowed to create or perform particular action.

Please check bundle identifier of your Application and match it with Settings in developer.facebook dashboard for your registered App.

If bundle identifier match and you are using your developer account for testing then it will allow you to publish action.

[image]